# How to ignore property in AutoMapper when projecting to a query but still have it mapped for results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have an entity that contains a DbGeography type that has a multi-polygon. I have mapped the DbGeography to a string[][]:

```
internal class DbGeographyAutoMapper : Profile
{
    public DbGeographyAutoMapper()
    {
        CreateMap<DbGeography, string[][]>()
            .ConvertUsing(geo =>
            {
                var maxElement = geo.ElementCount + 1;
                var rings = new string[geo.ElementCount.Value][];

                for (var elementIndex = 1; elementIndex < maxElement; elementIndex++)
                {
                    var currentElement = geo.ElementAt(elementIndex);

                    var latLngs = new string[currentElement.PointCount.Value];
                    var max = currentElement.PointCount + 1;

                    for (var i = 1; i < max; i++)
                    {
                        var point = currentElement.PointAt(i).EndPoint;
                        latLngs[i - 1] = $"{Math.Round(point.Latitude.Value, 4)},{Math.Round(point.Longitude.Value, 4)}";
                    }

                    rings[elementIndex - 1] = latLngs;
                }

                return rings;
            });
    }
}
```

And the entity to a model that contains a string[][]:

```
internal class WireCenterAutoMapper : Profile
{
    public WireCenterAutoMapper()
    {
        CreateMap<WireCenter, WirecenterModel>()
            .ForMember(m => m.Boundary, m => m.MapFrom(wc => wc.Boundary)) // This is the DbGeography to string[][]
            .ForMember(m => m.CLLI, m => m.MapFrom(wc => wc.CLLI))
            .ForMember(m => m.Id, m => m.MapFrom(wc => wc.Id))
            .ForMember(m => m.Name, m => m.MapFrom(wc => wc.OCN))
            .ForMember(m => m.Owner, m => m.MapFrom(wc => wc.Incumbent))
            .ForMember(m => m.State, m => m.MapFrom(wc => wc.State));
    }
}
```

When I try and project it to an IQueryable ...

```
[EnableQuery(PageSize = 500)]
public async Task<IQueryable<WirecenterModel>> Get([FromUri] BoundingBox intersects = null)
{
    return (await _wireCentersRepository.Find(intersects)).ProjectTo<WirecenterModel>();
}
```

... it blows up because the DbGeography uses a convert using. I would like to have that property mapped when converting it from the entity to the model, but ignored when projecting it to an EF Query. I did mark it as NotMapped...

```
/// <summary>
///     The Wire Center's boundary
/// </summary>
[NotMapped]
public string[][] Boundary { get; set; }
```

... but this did not help. How do I do this?

Comment: Later versions of AutoMapper departed from the static configuration. Now you can execute mappings with different profiles.

Comment: I saw that; however, not sure that helps here, as I need to ignore the Boundary in the projection to Entity Framework, but map the field back out to the model after whatever query the client requested has been applied.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem? I'm currently running into the same issue, but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was on vacation. No, I did not find a solution for this. I ended up not using IQueryable<T> for this particular endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I didn't want to map specifically during a `ProjectTo()`.

What worked for myself was the [ExplicitExpansion](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#explicit-expansion) setting:

```
internal class WireCenterAutoMapper : Profile
{
    public WireCenterAutoMapper()
    {
        CreateMap<WireCenter, WirecenterModel>()
            .ForMember(m => m.Boundary, opt => opt.ExplicitExpansion()) 
//...Followed by the rest of the code
    }
}
```

With this, LINQ projections won't map this value, leaving it null, unless you explicitly request it to be mapped in a projection.